# MVC / EF best way to deal with 0..1 relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I was hoping someone could clear something up for me with MVC / EF in relation to a 0..1 relationship between entities.

In my [hypothetical] database I have a table for colours and a table for fruits. I also have a lookup table which manages the relationship between colours and fruits as follows

Colours

```
ID    Name
1      Red
2      Green
3      Yellow
```

Fruits

```
ID   Name
1     Banana
2     Strawberry
```

Lookup

```
ColourId   FruitId
1            2
3            1
```

Lets say I want to display this information in a table using an MVC view and want it to look as follows:

```
Colour    Fruit
 Red    Strawberry
 Green    NULL
 Yellow   Banana
```

I can represent the above as models in MVC and then create a view model comprising of the models:

```
public class FruitViewModel
{
    public List<Colour> colours {get;set;}
    public List<Fruit> fruits {get;set}
}
```

Where would I go from here? Would I create a third model for fruit colour and add that into the view model? would this include a NULL fruit?

Comment: Wouldn't `Colour` simply have a `Fruits` property of type `List<Fruit>`?  (Assuming there can be more than one fruit of any given color?)  Then you wouldn't even need a view model, the view model would just be a `List<Colour>` and you'd iterate over that to render your table.

Comment: So Red can only be Strawberries and no other Fruit?

Comment: For the sake of this example, yes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a model for your cross-reference (lookup) table.

These are all that you need on your models:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

public class Color
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? FruitId { get; set; }
    public Fruit Fruit { get; set; }
}
```

Then depending on how you do your mappings (FluentApi vs Data Attributes), you just set up the relationship there.

For example in your Fruit Configuration:

```
HasRequired(f => f.Color)
    .WithOptional(c => c.Fruit)
    .Map(f => 
        {
            f.ToTable("Lookup");
            f.MapLeftKey("ColorId");
            f.MapRightKey("FruitId");
        });
```

Comment: This was made with the assumption that your actual problem isn't as simple as the example provided here. If it is that simple, then a collection on `Color` would make much more sense.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I can not quite get to work, I have implemented as per:
https://codeshare.io/alK9j5
but get the error " Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'FruitTest.Models.Fruit' and 'FruitTest.Models.Colour'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations." within the controller.

Comment: That's what the last portion of my answer is about. There is another way to do it with the attributes as well.